# Disable div with background color in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having div it contains child div's I need to disable and show gray color to parent div along with all child div's. I tried with CSS property `opacity` but background color is not setting for that. Please help me for how can I disable and show gray color.

I tried:

```
<div id="rtcontainer" load-complete data-ng-cloak=""
                style="left: 0px; top: 4px; width: 315px; height: auto; float: left; position: relative;">
<div><table><thead><tr><th></th></tr></thead></table></div>
<div><table></table></div>
</div>
```

I used this style:

```
  <style>
        .disabledbutton {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.1;   
}
    </style>
```

Jquery:

```
  $("#rtcontainer").addClass("disabledbutton");
```

I'm able to disable but I need to set background color like gray.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried removing that class using `$("#rtcontainer").removeClass("disabledbutton");`

Comment: Yes I tried `$("#rtcontainer").removeClass("disabledbutton");` in another condition

Comment: Did it work? @user123

Answer (score 0):

Put `background-color:gray` in the style

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#rtcontainer").addClass("disabledbutton");
})
```

```css
  
        .disabledbutton {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.3;   
    background-color:gray
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rtcontainer">aa
<div><table><thead><tr><th></th></tr></thead></table></div>
<div><table></table></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#rtcontainer div{
  background:gray;
  opacity:0.4;
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="rtcontainer">
  <div>
    <table border=1>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>heading</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div>
    <table border=1>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>heading</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try this.

Comment: Hi, I tried with the above both code but It's not changing background color when i added to my page. My page contains every div having styles

Comment: I tried with this also  `$('#right_container').prop('disabled', true);` not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `background-color:gray` and just use `#rtcontainer` for the selector in `css`.

```css
#rtcontainer {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.3;   
    background-color:gray
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rtcontainer">aa
<div><table><thead><tr><th></th></tr></thead></table></div>
<div><table></table></div>
</div>
```